# Save value in Transient model Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I added a new field in `account.config.settings` model. It displays the new field in settings page and can enter the value. But when i reopen the page the value is not there. I know the `Transient model` won't store values for long.

But rest of the values still there, how can i achieve this?
Below is my code.

***.py**

```
class AccountSettings(models.TransientModel):
_inherit='account.config.settings'

    @api.one
    def _get_header(self):

        header = fields.Char('Header')
```

***.xml**

```
<record id="view_account_config_settings_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">view.account.config.settings.inherit.form</field>
  <field name="model">account.config.settings</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_config_settings"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <xpath expr="//group[@name='accounting']" position="after">
    <group string="Reports" name="reports">
         <field name="header" class="oe_inline"/>
    </group>
  </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: May this help you http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/res.config.settings.html

Answer (score 2):

In `account.config.settings` Model you can save your value by using this :

```py
class AccountSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit='account.config.settings'

    header = fields.Char('Header')

    @api.multi
    def set_header_defaults(self):
        return self.env['ir.values'].sudo().set_default(
            'account.config.settings', 'header', self.header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class AccountSettings(models.TransientModel):
_inherit='account.config.settings'

    @api.one
    def _get_header(self):

        header = fields.Char('Header',config_parameter='header.configuration')
```

you can name the attribute `config_parameter` anything you want. And it will be used to get the value of header from other models.

example:

```
test = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('**header.configuration**', '').strip()
```

test will return the temporary stored value in `account.config.settings`.